# I wanted to sell my coins In DHL is the scam or a real buyer?

Tags: united-kingdom, scams

Please  help me I met a buyer of coins in Facebook who are DHL and he wants a delivery fee is that a scammer?

Because he want a delivery fee how is that impossible

Comment: what does DHL mean?

Comment: He wants a delivery fee?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep DHL in the UK almost invariably refers to a courier/parcel/shipping company.  The "buyer" presumably wants the OP to pay the delivery charge, before any payment they made is cancelled

Comment: Your grammar makes it difficult to interpret what you actually mean.  We can guess that someone wants you to pay the shipping fee for sending the coins to the alleged buyer, but we are not sure.

Answer (score 9):

Definitely a scam. Stop communicating with them.

Answer (score 7):

If somebody is buying something from you, then they are supposed to pay you money, not the other way round.

It's definitely a scam.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted?  It's the most sensible fraud check. If you sell something but you are supposed to pay money to the buyer, it simply doesn't make sense.